# Error on save: "can't open file for writing, too many files"

Tags: neovim, error

I was happily editing along when I tried to save and Neovim gave me this error
`"can't open file for writing, too many files"` and overriding with `!` did not help.
I decided because it had not been too long since last time I had successfully saved, I would simply quit, then reopen the file. Upon quitting, I discovered to my horror that the file was no longer present, and its `.swp` file was also not in `~/.local/share/nvim/swap` although others were there. I've been unsuccessful at recovering the file and am starting over with my project. But, what happened here and how do I prevent it? Yes, I could commit to my repo more often.
I had 1 browser open, and 6 buffers open in neovim, and entr was my task runner. I also tried `nvim -r <file>` but because the swp file is missing, it does nothing.

EDIT1:

- The path to my file was `~/projects/test/plet.nim`
- The dir `test` had fewer than 40 files.
- `entr` was watching only my 1 file `plet.nim` using the following invocation:

`ls plet.nim | entr -c bash -c "<compile command> && <run command>"`

Comment: Provide the directory structure of the files. "Can't open file for writing" happens mainly when there is a directory in the filename that doesn't exist, and since vim can't create intervening directories, it can't create the file which exists in the intervening directories. We need to know if this is the case you're facing.

Comment: Too many files is probably an OS-level error: you might have run out of file descriptors. This can happen when using `entr` with lots of files.

Comment: @3N4N, I've added what I think you are asking for in EDIT1

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, interesting - I've added my entr command in EDIT1. Do you see something bad practice here? Is it that entr can get itself into a bad state even when only working with 1 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the answer is that this was the fault of `entr` somehow having many file descriptors open, thus causing OS problems. I have not had issues since stopping using `entr`. Thanks to D. Ben Knoble for the suggestion.

Comment: You can usually increase the limit for this; the details for this depend on the system you're using.